# Error installing packages using composer?

Tags: php, composer-php, google-authentication

I want to `install googleauth` using composer but I am getting the error

> HTTP request failed

[image]

I have `composer.json` file in my working directory,

```
{
    "require":{
        "google/api-client":"dev-master"
    }
}
```

How to solve this error ?

Comment: i think you pointing into wrong package. The correct package is `google/apiclient`

Comment: Thanks man ......I somehow did not saw that :D